# In spring mvc how to get the context path in controller

Tags: java, spring, controller

I need application context path in controller, I tried the below code its throwing NULLPOINTER EXCEPTION.

> HttpServletRequest request;
>       String Path = request.getContextPath();

Please help me
Thanks

Comment: Assuming your "request" variable is actually instantiated somewhere else, this is syntactically that is correct, but you will need to provide more information/samples of your code for anyone to really help you.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

1. Variable `request` is declared, but is not
   initialized. No wonder you get a `NullPointerException`.
2. Look at [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-methods) to access different request related data.

After you read that, and are sure you want to tie your code to native Servlet API, try this:

```
@Controller
class MyController {

    @RequestMapping
    public void handleMe(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String path = request.getContextPath();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I tried  `public String toGenerateExcel(@RequestParam("projectId") int projectId,Model model,HttpServletRequest req)  
 {  String Path = req.getContextPath();` and I got the path thank u all..