# client upload images store under web root directory

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

in spring mvc inside entity class field name is file.

```
@Column
private String photo;
@Transient
private MultipartFile file;

//whatever the method setter/getter i want to store image in folder and file name in DB
public void setFile(MultipartFile file) {
     //file.getOriginalFilename()
     //add timestamp to filename
     //using file.transferTo(new File(....));
     //finally setPhoto(filename_with_timestamp)
}
```

Here (in entity class) how to get servlet contextpath then real path to store images in working directory?

please any one help me

Comment: the core of the question is a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17654333/in-spring-mvc-how-to-get-the-context-path-in-controller

Answer (score 0):

**For security reasons it is not recommended to let an user upload anything in the web root directory!**

The better way is to store the uploaded files in an directory outside the Web Root (outside the web-server directory).

Comment: its ok, how do i get context path in entity class using spring ioc or any other.