# Spring MVC - How Return View To Correct Context Root

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

My spring mvc application was built and deployed on root url "/" using glassfish server.

http://mydomain/

Now I want to deploy a new version using other context path like "v2/"

http://mydomain/v2

But when I run using a non-root path the controller try to return to "/" not to "v2"

Example:

- Access http://mydomain/v2/login
- When I execute the authentication the controller send me to: http://mydomain/home
- Should be: http://mydomain/v2/home

Here is my controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/admin/home", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView adminOperationsPage() {
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        model.setViewName("/admin/home");
        return model;
    }
```

My viewResolver:

```
@Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/pages/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewResolver;
    }
```

How can I take into account the Context Root "v2" on returning the view?

http://mydomain/v2/home
instead of 
http://mydomain/home

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was doing a redirect mistake into authentication and this was my problem..

Anyway, I can try help some future **beginners issues**:

**To change your context-path:**

http://domain/ to http://domain/NewContextRoot/

Edit your server configuration xml and add ContextRoot param, in my case I'm using glassfish 4.1.1 and then I edit my "glassfish-web.xml" adding this line:

Configuration for http://domain/

```
<glassfish-web-app>
   <context-root>/</context-root>
</glassfish-web-app>
```

Configuration for http://domain/NewContextRoot/

```
<glassfish-web-app>
   <context-root>/NewContextRoot</context-root>
</glassfish-web-app>
```

In fact some guys say to you rename your .war file or change your artifactId (pom file) to your server get the name by default and create this context root but I disagree with those resolutions, your are losing the control of your application doing that. If you want deploy multiple instances you should take into into account.

From:

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31005066/how-to-set-spring-root-context-path](http://reference_1)

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2437465/how-to-change-context-root-of-a-dynamic-web-project-in-eclipse](http://reference_2)

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/664059/how-do-you-specify-the-root-context-in-your-web-app-tags-in-web-xml](http://reference_3)

But if I do not use glassfish? Simple: all servers allow you create a server configuration file, you just need find the name correctly glassfish-web.xml, jboss-web.xml, etc... And put it on "WEB-INF"...

**To add your new context-path into your jsp files:**

Use ${pageContext.request.contextPath}

From:

[Spring MVC: Url path appending when posting the form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18631147/spring-mvc-url-path-appending-when-posting-the-form)

[Spring MVC Request URLs in JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6970115/spring-mvc-request-urls-in-jsp)

**To you get the new context root into your spring controller**:

```
@Controller
class MyController {

    @RequestMapping
    public void handleMe(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String path = request.getContextPath();
    }
}
```

From:

[In spring mvc how to get the context path in controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17654333/in-spring-mvc-how-to-get-the-context-path-in-controller)

Hope it helps =D